# How to disable display error message in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

- I am trying to place an order for the product **FELINE/CANINE SPAY PACK**
  in store I am getting struck at shipping methods.
- I am viewing the display error message like, **This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.**
- May I know why I am viewing that error message. I am unable to find out the solution for this issue.
- Can someone suggest me to get rid of this issue? Is a problem with the product or with shipping methods?
- What changes should I do in backend Magento 1.9? Please guys suggest something.

Comment: ITs not an error, the product which is in your cart is not eligible for shipping , just check shipping method setting in admin pannel

Comment: Thanks for your response.But the problem is not with the product, cuz for all the products i see same display error message.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Shipping Method` from `Configuration` and find your shipping method and make sure you `Show Method if Not Applicable` to set `No`

If you would like to change or remove error message you can do it from `Displayed Error Message` [Screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/om58rNAJqD)

Comment: Thanks for the response. suggestion which you gave is already in a same manner shipping method>config>show method if not applicable is already set to NO though am viewing that display error message while am placing order.